# How to attach more than two text file in email with editable email notificaton plugin in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

i have more than 2 text files generating after running a particular job in jenkins and i want to attach this two text files in email-triggered after success of the job.

Here we are using Editable email plugin, through which we can attach only one file no more that one, any please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editable Email Notification has an Attachment section and it use Ant script.when you require an email trigger at the end of your build including files as an attachment then it will be helpful for you to know Ant script work mainly on relative addressing rather than absolute addressing. so content in attachment pattern should be some thing like this

```
**/foldername/*.txt
```

(anyextension)

Note:make sure the folder exists in your job workspace and  all your text files are placed in that folder.

Or the other way if you have files in workspace , then you can use a comma separated list of file names to trigger as an attachment.

Please Use Trigger in email ext plugin and use success Trigger.

Hope this helps to some extent